# Cannot use Dictionary

Tags: macos, mac, dictionary

When I Try to use Apple's built in dictionary, I only get Wikipedia:

[image]

As you can see, I have enabled English and Français, But I only get Wikipedia. I also don't have the 'Apple Dictionary' in the Reference Sources.

Comment: What version of Mac OS are you using?  If you go to the folder `/Library/Dictionaries`, what do you see?

Comment: I only have a `Library/DictionariesDisabled`. No dictionaries. I am running macOS Sierra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the macOS 10.12 Sierra GM (Golden Master).

Apple has released a few more builds since its keynote on September 7. The first build was 16A320.

To update to the current build there are two options:

1. Wait until macOS Sierra's release date (tomorrow, September 20)
2. Download the latest macOS Sierra installer from the developer center.

What is your current macOS Sierra build number?

Comment: I have the same problem with a fresh installation of Catalina. The problem appeared after using the Assistant Migration.